# JS: Push outside-defined object into array inside for loop, why always show the last not the first, why console.log works?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, push

Javascript, when pushing outside-defined object into array in a for loop, the last one is repeatedly pushed.

I read many Q/A (see below links) and know the solution, but did not find explanation for the follwing 2 points:

1. before and after the push, console.log the obj, it shows properly all objects (not repeating the last one), but push works only the last one;
2. If object defined outside is "always the same object", why not repeat the first one, but repeat the last one?

Related Q/A:

[How to push object to array from for loop properly in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602160/how-to-push-object-to-array-from-for-loop-properly-in-javascript)

[React push object into array, always pushed last array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911994/react-push-object-into-array-always-pushed-last-array)

[After pushing objects into array, every object in the array has the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601069/after-pushing-objects-into-array-every-object-in-the-array-has-the-same-value)

```
let arr = [];
let obj = {};

for(let i=0; i<5; i++) {
  obj["single"] = i;
  obj["double"] = i*2;
  console.log(obj);
  arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

result:

```
{ single: 0, double: 0 }
{ single: 1, double: 2 }   
{ single: 2, double: 4 }   
{ single: 3, double: 6 }   
{ single: 4, double: 8 }   

[
  { single: 4, double: 8 },
  { single: 4, double: 8 },
  { single: 4, double: 8 },
  { single: 4, double: 8 },
  { single: 4, double: 8 } 
]
```

Comment: Create a new object each time, instead of mutating and push the same object - `arr.push({ single: i, double: i * 2 });`.

Comment: Thanks, I know the solution. but cannot understand the reason.

Comment: You have a single object, and you have an array with 5 slots, that each of them points at the same object. Whenever you change the object, all the slots show the same values, because they reference the same object. Try `console.log(arr[0] === arr[1])`, and you'll get `true`, and them same thing would happen for any pair combination.

Comment: thanks, I think I understand. the array stored a pointer to the obj. the value of the obj is continuously updated. right?

Comment: Yep. You mutate the same object all the time, so all slots show the last update.